# MySQL unable to access data encrypted using gzdeflate()

Tags: mysql, sql, binary, compression

I have a mysql database entry which looks like:

```
Id | Key

1  | +ÎÏ)-IMÉ+Ö+É
```

This key is encrypted using gzdeflate() function. The problem is, I cannot access this entry. When I try to run this MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `keys` WHERE `Key` = '+ÎÏ)-IMÉ+Ö+É'
```

The result is empty! How can I access it? I know I can do it using WHERE LIKE, but I want a single result from the query and not multiple.

Comment: Which MySQL API are you using?

Comment: gzdeflate isn't encryption, it's just compression.

Comment: Compression produces binary data, there's probably some non-printing characters in there.

Comment: It is exactly the same, I've tried gzinflate() on it and the result was correct. And I am not using MySQL API, I'm executing the statement on phpMyAdmin

Comment: Why would you need to search using binary data like that?

Comment: The key is compressed to this form, I will de-compress it using gzinflate() later. But the question is, why isn't it showing?

Comment: What data type is `Key`?